# CakePHP 4 do not get new added fields from DB

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have some trouble getting content of a new created field from Database. 
At the beginning i created my "Menue" table in phpmyadmin and then in cake with "bin/cake bake all Menue". So far so good. But i forgot a field "price" which i added right now in the database and filled it with content.
In cake i added this field "price" in src/Model/Entitiy/Menue and src/Table/MenuesTable.php. In the Controller src/Controller/MenuesController i wanted to get the price with $menue->price but there is no field key or content. Also print_r($menue); return all other fields and content but not the price field. 
is there another file where i have to add this field?
In phpmyadmin i can do a simple sql statement and i get this field with content in the results... so i am thinking cake is missing something.

Thanks in advance!

The following query was created by the bake command.

```
$menue = $this->Menues->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Restaurants'],
        ]);
```

also a self written query do do deliver the field "price"

```
$menue = $this->Menues
            ->find()
            ->where(['id ='=>$id]);
        foreach($menue as $m){
          print_r($m);
        }
```

I just figured out, that this field and a again newly created "test" field are loaded in another Controller written by hand with

```
$this->loadModel('Menues');
...
$contents = $this->Menues
                    ->find()
                    ->select(['id',
                        'title',
                        'short_description',
                        'additives',
                        'price',
                        'currency',
                        'image_path'
                        'test'
                    ])
                    ->where(['restaurant_id =' => $restaurant_id,'menuegroup' => $cat['menuegroup']])
                    ->order(['sort_order' => 'ASC']);
```

But why my other controller do not want to give me the price is still a question i can not answer. maybe someone knows.
THX

Comment: try: bin/cake cache clear_all

Comment: okay, this is hard. it is working now after using this clear_all and i tried hours and its so easy ... i put this on "my try this on error" list. Best, thank you!